# Not exists - should be returning something but isn't

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make sure the selected info isn't in string values of another table when it's selected from a different table.  Here's the abbreviated data info/examples in a nutshell:

```
create table #temp_VMC
(t_id varchar(25),
CID int,
conc_id int, 
str_val nvarchar(3000))
```

here's an example of data in that table...note that there are cases in this table that don't have a cm and we don't care about those ones

```
t_id  CID   conc_id    str_val  
678   76543 501000     0070
789   80000 560000     0030
890   90000 530000     0001

o_info
subject                       body
Manual Task Created: 000789   <><Created by Mary Smith>
stamp                         <><question 1 true>

select * from #temp_vmc um
where not exists
(
select * from o_info with (NOLOCK) where subject LIKE '%Manual Task Created: '+um.t_id+'%' 
)
```

So I know that the select * from o_info doesn't turn up anything, so if my select * from #temp_vmc has one row, shouldn't I still get one row with them together?

*Update: I tried selecting this, and nothing turns up, so the where not exists should return the row I know is in temp_vmc:

```
select * from o_info with (NOLOCK) where subject LIKE '%'+um.t_id+'%'
```

It looks like I'm using not exists correctly according to this link: [not exists](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp)

Comment: I would assume that the same person answering one could answer both questions.  If I get separate people answering each thing, I can decide who is more useful and upvote one and accept the other as answer...  I don't want to flood the website with multiple questions with an almost identical writeup.

Comment: I edited the question so it's just one question now.  Different than original question.

Comment: `where subject LIKE '%um.t_id%'` has nothing to do with your issue  because you are using the string literal `'um.t_id'` and not `um.t_id`. What is `t_id`? I don't see it in the table's definition. Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo, so I fixed the string in the question.  Also added o_info above. Last I checked, fiddle won't let me save/share.

Comment: Everything is working here correctly, you must have some typo (or have corrected it) in your preparation for SO posting. One thing to notice that your t_id = '789', but subject includes '000789' - thereby first exists() doesn't match. For second query no such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the EXISTS correltated subquery, you are searching for

```
LIKE '%Manual Task Created: '+um.t_id+'%'
```

Given your data, that becomes

```
LIKE '%Manual Task Created: 678%'
LIKE '%Manual Task Created: 789%'
LIKE '%Manual Task Created: 890%'
```

However, the data you are searching would appear to be in the form of

```
Manual Task Created: 000789
```

that is, with leading zeroes. Thus, the data will never match. This is probably throwing your query logic off.

Comment: I added more data and it's working now.  Not sure why it wasn't working. Thanks!!  :)